# Python Unicode Handling

Tags: python, unicode

I've looked through several questions and I can't seem to find the exact answer to what I need.

I am trying to figure out how to take an emoji and use unicodedata.name() to return it's name.

So for example, I have this emoji: .
I want to be able to get it's identifier and get the value of it's name (PILE OF POO).  I want to know how to construct the string to pass in to the name function:

```
unicodedata.name(u'\U0001f4a9')
```

The above code works.  However passing as such:

```
unicodedata.name()
```

returns the following:

```
mojidict['hi'] = unicodedata.name(\U0001f4a9)                                     ^                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: You need to quote the pile of poo. Otherwise you are trying to use it as an identifier instead of a string or character value.

Comment: Right.  I just discovered that.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple:

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.name('')
```

which returns:

```
'PILE OF POO'
```

Comment: Yup.  I just discovered this dumb mistake.  Thank you!

Comment: You may also need to [declare the encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) of the source file.